# Iptables - Limit SMTP output traffic

Tags: iptables, smtp

I'd like to limit the output smtp traffic of my server (Debian). For example : only 10 mails per seconds.

I want to use Iptables for this purpose.

I tried :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 25 -m limit --limit 10/s -j ACCEPT
```

But i assumes to have a REJECT policy in output and I'd like to avoid.

How can I do ?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish? What software is involved (postfix, etc.)? I assume you want to limit emails originating from your server itself, not a client connected to your server?

Comment: isame as @Lenniey : why do you need to use iptables ? it does not seem to be suited for this need, where the actual MTA configuration can deal with it easily.

Comment: I am using Sendmail. However I didn't find any solution for limit mail per hour on the sendmail configuration.
Yes I want to limit emails from the server itself.